# Continuous on a disk, smooth on a disk minus a closed interval. Does it extend?

Tags: smooth-functions

Suppose $u:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, where $\mathbb{D}$ is the open unit disk. Let $I$ be a closed segment in $\mathbb{D}$. To make things simpler we can suppose $I=[a,b]$ is a closed interval in $\mathbb{R}\cap\mathbb{D}$. Suppose that $u:\mathbb{D}\setminus I\to\mathbb{R}$ is smooth. Can $u$ extend to being smooth on all of $\mathbb{D}$? If not, what extra conditions could we put on $u$ to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: Does smooth mean infinitely differentiable?

Comment: @norfair Yes, it does